# Local IP and External IP in Mobile Internet

Tags: networking, ip-address

Using a network tool in an android phone, I found the Local IP and External IP as:
[image]

I believe both are the Public IP.

Pls be kind and let me know, what is Local IP and External IP in this scenario?

Regards 
TekQ

Answer (score 0):

The Local IP is the address that your provider (Verizon, AT&T, Sprint, etc...) uses to identify you on *their* network.  The External IP is the address that websites (google.com, facebook.com, etc...) use to identify and communicate with you.

There is a translation process, known as Network Address Translation (NAT), that converts Local IP addresses into External/Public IP addresses.  The NAT service is controlled by your cell network provider.

More information can be found on [Wikipedia's Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) page.